# Can UI design patterns be patented?

Tags: design-patterns, visual-design

Just like any other product innovations safeguarded with patents, are there any provisions for UX design patterns to be patented?

Does anyone know of any research related to design patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of provisions to have your design protected.

What you can essentially patent is not how the colours are applied to the design pattern that you have put in considerable amount of efforts but how the structure of your design is and what is the interaction involved.

I have checked multiple places about this and have shared thoughts to my fellow colleagues in my current organization. you can refer to below article very well written by Christie Tang

https://onezero.medium.com/the-ui-ux-patterns-you-literally-cant-use-64875a5c965f

A quick example to show what it typically looks like is below

**Spotify**: Spotify’s “Shuffle Play” button is patented in its half-header style.

[image: A mobile screenshot showing Spotify's "Shuffle Play" button. The button is approximately half of the device's width, centered, and pinned in a position just under the title of the scrollable playlist.]

[image: The patent sketch for Spotify's half-header UI component.]